# Rearrange sequence of months in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm populating an array with set of months like this:

```
var months=["March 2016","April 2016","May 2016","January 2015","February 2016"]
```

How can I rearrange the months in order like this below considering the year as well..:

```
var months=["January 2015","February 2016","March 2016","April 2016","May 2016",]
```

I tried to sort() the months that will sort alphabetically which is not logical.Any suggestions for this prob??

Comment: _"I'm populating an array"_ -> is the data already in the form of these strings when populating, or do you have access to the data in a different form (eg actual date objects) at this time?

Comment: use foreach with key value pair ,,,, split the value ..first arrange it with respect to number (i.e. year ) Than create your own array like 1=> January , 2=>february , 3=> March  and so on... Use this array to sort with respect to month ( when you have a sorted array with respect to year already)

Comment: Does the year have any bearing on the required sort order?

Comment: Yes,@Xotic750.It has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object with their month's order values and sort it by the year and the month value.

```js
var months = ["March 2016", "April 2016", "May 2016", "January 2015", "February 2016"];

months.sort(function (a, b) {
    var MONTH = { January: 0, February: 1, March: 2, April: 3, May: 4, June: 5, July: 6, August: 7, September: 8, October: 9, November: 10, December: 11 },
        aa = a.split(' '),
        bb = b.split(' ');
    return aa[1] - bb[1] || MONTH[aa[0]] - MONTH[bb[0]];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(months, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert both to a Date object and then use sort

```
["March 2016","April 2016","May 2016","January 2015","February 2016"].sort(function(a, b) { 
     return new Date("1 " + a) - new Date("1 " + b); 
})
```

---

Edit : Thanks @Hacketo for pointing out that the `getTime()` (in the original version of the answer) is not actually required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Array that contain a list of months as reference, then check the index.

```
var months=["March 2015","April 2016","May 2016","January 2015","February 2016"];
var m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

months.sort(function(a,b){
    var yearA = a.split(" ")[1];
    var yearB = b.split(" ")[1];
    if (yearA != yearB){ return +yearA - +yearB ;}
    return m.indexOf(a.split(" ")[0]) -  m.indexOf(b.split(" ")[0]);
});

// ["January 2015", "March 2015", "February 2016", "April 2016", "May 2016"]
```